# Systemd service starts with enable/start command but does nothing on startup

Tags: systemd

I have a simple script which set keyboard back-light to 0 on startup. It work if invoked manually. 
And I have service which should invoke it on startup.

```
[Unit]
Description=Power_off keyboard backlight on startup

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/kbd_to_zero
RemainAfterExit=yes
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

And this service works fine when running command systemctl enable now or start.
But it does nothing on startup.
journalctl says that

```
січ 24 02:05:35 dmytro-VivoBook-S15-X530UA systemd[1]: Starting Power_off keyboard backlight on startup...
січ 24 02:05:35 dmytro-VivoBook-S15-X530UA sudo[3370]: root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tee /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
січ 24 02:05:35 dmytro-VivoBook-S15-X530UA sudo[3370]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
січ 24 02:05:35 dmytro-VivoBook-S15-X530UA kbd_to_zero[3364]: 0
січ 24 02:05:35 dmytro-VivoBook-S15-X530UA sudo[3370]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
січ 24 02:05:35 dmytro-VivoBook-S15-X530UA systemd[1]: Started Power_off keyboard backlight on startup.
```

What I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try running the enable command? Assuming your service is called keyboard-backlight.service, try running the following: `systemctl enable keyboard-backlight.service`.

Comment: Yes. It instantly set back-light to zero. Then I set it back and rebooted and nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. That was the solution. I was sure that I had tried enable without now. Now everything works.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "tried enable without now", but I'm glad to hear everything's working for you. :-)